# Low performance in queries using $where even with non-existing collections

Tags: mongodb

I implemented in my code the following sequence on a MongoDB server: 1) query the "entities" collection, 2) update the "entities" collection and 3) query the "csubs" collection. The last one (query on "csubs" collection) uses a `$where` operator.

I'm running a test which executes the above three-steps sequence hundreds of times per second. As precondition for this test, "csubs" collection is empty (i.e. `shows collection` doesn't even show it). Thus, intuition says that step 3) should be ultra-fast.

I have done the test both with MongoDB 2.4 and MongoDB 2.6, getting the following results with `mongotop` ("qatest" is the name of the DB):

MongoDB 2.4.9:

```
                        ns       total        read       write     
           qatest.entities       451ms       189ms       262ms
              qatest.csubs       447ms       447ms         0ms
```

MongoDB 2.6.10:

```
                        ns       total        read       write
              qatest.csubs      2315ms      2315ms         0ms
           qatest.entities       121ms        54ms        67ms
```

Based on this results, I have two questions:

1. Why is query on "csubs" so slow? I understand that the usage of `$where` could have a query cost but I have expected that cost to be proportional to the number of documents to process in the target collection. But in this case, the documents number in the collection is 0, given that the collection doesn't exist. Is there any "bootstraping" cost related with `$where` (e.g. creating a JavaScript VM context to execute the query) associated to the query itself and independent of the collection (and its size) to be queried?
2. Assuming that such bootstraping cost exist, why is so different from MongoDB 2.4 and MongoDB 2.6? In particular, it gets worse in MongoDB 2.6 (which I understand should be more advanced, from a performance point of view). Has the way in which server JavaScript works changed in MongoDB 2.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, it is confirmed that it is due to a "bootstrapping" cost that happens in MongoDB 2.6 but not in MongoDB 2.4. See this ticket in [the MongoDB JIRA tracker](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12934) for more information.